# Iterate over all html element and modify the contents

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am working with a project which requires the iteration over each element of an external html  file and  modify the contents withing the inner tag.

I want a recursive java script function that would iterate all the DOM element and modify the content within each inner tag by appending # at beginning and end.

```html
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Hello</h1> 
        <div id="something"><span><h1>Hello Folks!</h1></span></div>
        <span>Lovely lady</span>
        <div id="name">
            <div class="random">
                <div><span>0</span></div>
                <div><span>1</span></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="detail ">
            <div class="">Process</div>
            <div class="page">4 of 6</div>
            <div class=" ">
                <div class="float-left">
                    <div class="padding-top-default">%</div>
                    <div class="page-subheader">1</div>
                </div>
                <div class="">
                    <div class="">Failed</div>
                    <div class="page-subheader font-big">0</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>

</html>
```

I want # appended if the value is hardcoded within the tag. The output file would be like.

```html
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>#Hello#</h1> 
        <div id="something"><span><h1>#Hello Folks!#</h1></span></div>
        <span>#Lovely lady#</span>
        <div id="name">
            <div class="random">
                <div><span>#0#</span></div>
                <div><span>#1#</span></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="detail ">
            <div class="">#Process#</div>
            <div class="page">#4 of 6#</div>
            <div class=" ">
                <div class="float-left">
                    <div class="padding-top-default">#%#</div>
                    <div class="page-subheader">#1#</div>
                </div>
                <div class="">
                    <div class="">#Failed#</div>
                    <div class="page-subheader font-big">#0#</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>

</html>
```

I have this java script in place

```js
 <script>
            
          
          //$fakediv = $("<div></div>"); 
        function convertHtml() {
            
 
            $body = $("#demo").text();
             
           $fakediv = $("<div></div>");
            $fakediv.html($body); 
            $fakediv.children().each(function() {
                   if($(this).text())  
                   $(this).text("#" + $(this).text() + "#");
              });
            
            });
          $("#demo").text($fakediv.prop("outerHTML")); //fill in the text are with converted html string 
        
}
            
        //Document is ready to execute the JS    
        $(document).ready(function() {    
            $("#convert").click(function(){
              // alert($("#demo").text());
                convertHtml();
            }); 
        });
        </script>
```

But whats happening the output is like

```html
<div>
    
    
    
        <h1>#Hello#</h1> 
        <div id="something">#Hello Folks!#</div>
        <span>#Lovely lady#</span>
        <div id="name">#
            
                0
                1
            
        #</div>
        <div class="detail ">#
            Process
            4 of 6
            
                
                    %
                    1
                
                
                    Failed
                    0
                
            
        #</div>
    

</div>
```

Comment: If any body want to see what actually i am doing please leave a message i would rather like to come one to one to clarify my question

Comment: Please don't abuse web-snippet function. It exists solely for runnable web code. If the code is not runnable, use normal source code formatting (indenting by four spaces, or using ctrl-K).

Answer (score 3):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('body').find('*').each(function() {
    if ($(this).children().length == 0) {
      $(this).prepend('#').append('#')
    }
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Hello</h1> 
        <div id="something"><span><h1>Hello Folks!</h1></span></div>
        <span>Lovely lady</span>
        <div id="name">
            <div class="random">
                <div><span>0</span></div>
                <div><span>1</span></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="detail ">
            <div class="">Process</div>
            <div class="page">4 of 6</div>
            <div class=" ">
                <div class="float-left">
                    <div class="padding-top-default">%</div>
                    <div class="page-subheader">1</div>
                </div>
                <div class="">
                    <div class="">Failed</div>
                    <div class="page-subheader font-big">0</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Lazy version (will not do anything to `"foo"` in `<p>foo <em>bar</em></p>`):

```js
var html = '<html>\n    <head>\n    </head>\n    <body>\n        <h1>Hello</h1> \n        <div id="something"><span><h1>Hello Folks!</h1></span></div>\n        <span>Lovely lady</span>\n        <div id="name">\n            <div class="random">\n                <div><span>0</span></div>\n                <div><span>1</span></div>\n            </div>\n        </div>\n        <div class="detail ">\n            <div class="">Process</div>\n            <div class="page">4 of 6</div>\n            <div class=" ">\n                <div class="float-left">\n                    <div class="padding-top-default">%</div>\n                    <div class="page-subheader">1</div>\n                </div>\n                <div class="">\n                    <div class="">Failed</div>\n                    <div class="page-subheader font-big">0</div>\n                </div>\n            </div>\n        </div>\n    </body>\n\n</html>\n';
    
$html = $("<html/>").html(html);
$html.find('*:not(:has(*))').text(function(_, txt) {
if (txt.trim() == "") return "";
  return "#" + txt + "#";
});
$('#output').text($html[0].outerHTML);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<pre id="output"></pre>
```

A non-lazy version involves finding all text nodes in the document, which jQuery doesn't know how to do, so we'll employ a tree walker. Bonus, no jQuery:

```js
var html = '<html>\n    <head>\n    </head>\n    <body>\n        <h1>Hello</h1> \n        <div id="something"><span><h1>Hello Folks!</h1></span></div>\n        <span>Lovely lady</span>\n        <div id="name">\n            <div class="random">\n                <div><span>0</span></div>\n                <div><span>1</span></div>\n            </div>\n        </div>\n        <div class="detail ">\n            <div class="">Process</div>\n            <div class="page">4 of 6</div>\n            <div class=" ">\n                <div class="float-left">\n                    <div class="padding-top-default">%</div>\n                    <div class="page-subheader">1</div>\n                </div>\n                <div class="">\n                    <div class="">Failed</div>\n                    <div class="page-subheader font-big">0</div>\n                </div>\n            </div>\n        </div>\n    </body>\n\n</html>\n';

var impl    = document.implementation;
var htmlDoc = impl.createHTMLDocument("");
htmlDoc.write(html);

var walker = htmlDoc.createTreeWalker(
    htmlDoc.documentElement,
    NodeFilter.SHOW_TEXT, null, false);
var node;
while ((node = walker.nextNode())) {
  if (node.textContent.trim() !== "") {
    node.textContent = "#" + node.textContent + "#";
  }
}

document.getElementById('output').textContent = htmlDoc.documentElement.innerHTML;
```

```html
<pre id="output"></pre>
```

Note that due to certain details of HTML parsing, things outside `<body>` will likely not be the same. And the note that DBagBaggerWithSwagger had over another solution is valid here as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [text function](http://api.jquery.com/text/#text-function)

```
$('body *').text(function(_, txt){
   return '#'+txt+'#';
});
```

Here's a [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/xezo81u4/)

If there's any style rules and javascripts inside the body then you can ignore them using [not](http://api.jquery.com/not):

```
$('body *').not('link,style,script').text(function(_, txt){
       return '#'+txt+'#';
});
```

Comment: This is an external html file and and i need to show the modified source code within a div element

Comment: Now it will only kill all markup that is not `link,style,script`. You need something like `$('*:not(> *)')` to prevent elements that have children from performing filicide. Or, depending on what OP wants, you want to find all text nodes (which jQuery doesn't know how to do) and only wrap them.

Answer (score 0):

Give a class to all the elements whose text you want to wrapped with `#`. and then use the following code :

```
$('.hashed').each(function(index, value){
    $(this).text("#" + $(this).text() + "#");
});
```

Well if you cannot edit the html than use the following css to select deepest elements:

```
'*:not(:has(>*))'
```

Here is the working code :

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('*:not(:has(>*))').each(function(index, value){
    $(this).text("#" + $(this).text() + "#");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Hello</h1> 
        <div id="something"><span><h1>Hello Folks!</h1></span></div>
        <span>Lovely lady</span>
        <div id="name">
            <div class="random">
                <div><span>0</span></div>
                <div><span>1</span></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="detail">
            <div>Process</div>
            <div class="page">4 of 6</div>
            <div class=" ">
                <div class="float-left">
                    <div class="padding-top-default">%</div>
                    <div class="page-subheader">1</div>
                </div>
                <div class="">
                    <div>Failed</div>
                    <div class="page-subheader font-big">0</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is an external file and i can not add classes to each of my tag which need to be modified. Then what might be the possible solution.

Comment: @AkAbhi then you can use css selector to select all the deepest elements. and then perform operation over them. Edited my post.

Comment: Thats the problem we can not modify the content of DOM using CSS. Insted have a look over my edited post.

Comment: Hi Mr. Afzal, can you please explain the usage of '*:not(:has(>*))'

Comment: @Sarwan `:not(:has(>*))` is the css selector to select elements that do not have children.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go. Unlike the others, this *will not* add `'##'` to tags without content, like `img`, `br`, empty `span`s, etc...

```
function eachNode($root) {
    if ($root.children().size() == 0) {
        if ($root.text().trim() !== '') $root.text('#' + $root.text() + '#');
    } else {
        $root.children().each(function () {
            eachNode($(this));
        });
    }
}

eachNode($(document));
```

Checkout the fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/hra0qste/2/

Comment: Note that this does not avoid modifying `script` tags, but this can be easily added via `if($root[0].tagName === 'SCRIPT') return`

Answer (score 0):

This should also work:

```
function isHTML(str) {
    var a = document.createElement('div');
    a.innerHTML = str;
    for (var c = a.childNodes, i = c.length; i--; ) {
        if (c[i].nodeType == 1) return true; 
    }
    return false;
}

$( document ).ready(function() {
    var content =   document.getElementsByTagName('*');
    for ( var i = 0; i < content.length; i++ )
    {
        if ( isHTML($(content[i]).html()) == false ) 
        {
            $(content[i]).html('#' + $(content[i]).html() + '#');   
        }          
    }
});
```